# Optimize linq by avoiding if else condition

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have one DropDownList that populates Gender.

The selected value for male is `1` and femail is `2`.

Based on the selected value I need to retrieve data from database.

```
if (ddlGender==1)
{
    var data= (from item in dbContext.Sample where item.locId > 100 select item);
}
else
{
    var data= (from item in dbContext.Sample where item.locId <100 select item);
}
```

How can I optimize this code by avoiding if condition and by using only single LINQ?

Comment: You can not avoid some kind of condition here.

Comment: don't do optimization unless it is necessary. This code isn't a source of bottleneck and you won't gain anything, even if you avoid the condition.

Comment: I'm not really sure why you'd want to "optimize" away the `if` statement. It's virtually instantaneous compared to the data access. I think what you've got there is fine.

Comment: How do you want to program without conditional statements? This is the base of every programming language.

Comment: I was thinking about Lambda expression but as the `ddlGender` is outside of the query, trying to use it inside the query requires an `if` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var data = from item in dbContect.Sample 
where (item.locId > 100 && ddlGender == 1) || 
(item.locId < 100 && ddlGender != 1)
select item
```

Comment: +1 for removing if-else, but will this affect the performance as the conditions performed on each item is increased ?

Comment: if the intention is having a single query in linq that is a possible solution. for the incresed performance, depend from how many item are present in table. probably there is a small increase negligible if the are a few rows.

Comment: I think this code will perform worse than the original code. The original code will cause one of two simple queries to be executed on the database, depending on the value of `ddlGender`. This code needlessly pushes the decision to the database server, making a more complex query.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is composing query with filter and usage of ternary operator:

```
var data = dbContext.Sample;
data = (ddlGender == 1) ? data.Where(i => i.locId > 100) 
                        : data.Where(i => i.locId < 100);
```

This option eliminates duplication, does not have any overhead with additional conditions on generated query (see update), also I find it pretty readable. I would also suggest to give some sensible name to constant `100`.

UPDATE: Query above will generate simple and clear SQL

```
SELECT [Extent1].[locId] AS [locId],
       [Extent1].[Foo] AS [Foo],
       [Extent1].[Bar] AS [Bar]
FROM [dbo].[Sample] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[locId] > 100
```

If you will add complex condition, it will be translated to SQL. E.g.

```
(item.locId > 100 && ddlGender == 1) || (item.locId < 100 && ddlGender != 1)
```

Will be translated to following query with two parameters (assume you have non-nullable field locId in database)

```
SELECT [Extent1].[locId] AS [locId],
       [Extent1].[Foo] AS [Foo],
       [Extent1].[Bar] AS [Bar]
FROM [dbo].[Sample] AS [Extent1]
WHERE (([Extent1].[locId] > 100) AND (1 = @p_linq_0) AND (@p_linq_0 IS NOT NULL))
   OR (([Extent1].[locId] < 100) AND 
       (NOT ((1 = @p_linq_1) AND (@p_linq_1 IS NOT NULL))))
```

Comment: +1. This doesn't really "optimize" the original code (which was pretty optimal as it was), but it is shorter and neater.

Comment: @BenM thanks! Actually I was talking about optimizing code which another answer here has - when you add all conditions in where statement, I will update answer to point on that :)